# nodejs with docker and postgress: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND

Tags: node.js, postgresql, docker, typeorm

Hello I don't know what else to do to resolve this error:

```
    ci-api    | Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND ${DB_HOST}
    ci-api    |     at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:66:26) {
    ci-api    |   errno: 'ENOTFOUND',
    ci-api    |   code: 'ENOTFOUND',
    ci-api    |   syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
    ci-api    |   hostname: '${DB_HOST}'
    ci-api    | }
```

I have a `.env` file with the following variables:

**`.env` file:**

```
    SERVER_PORT=4000
    DB_HOST=db-pg
    DB_PORT=5432
    DB_USER=spirit
    DB_PASS=api
    DB_NAME=emasa_ci
```

**`DockerFile`**:

```
    #building code
    FROM node:lts-alpine

    ADD https://github.com/ufoscout/docker-compose-wait/releases/download/2.7.3/wait /wait
    RUN chmod +x /wait

    RUN mkdir -p /home/node/api && chown -R node:node /home/node/api

    WORKDIR /home/node/api

    COPY ormconfig.json .env package.json yarn.* ./

    USER node

    RUN yarn

    COPY --chown=node:node . .
    EXPOSE 4000

**My `docker-compose`:**

    version: '3.7'
    services:
      db-pg:
        image: postgres:12
        container_name: db-pg
        ports:
          - '${DB_PORT}:5432'
        environment:
          ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 'no'
          POSTGRES_USER: ${DB_USER}
          POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASS}
          POSTGRES_DB: ${DB_NAME}
        volumes:
          - ci-postgres-data:/data

      ci-api:
        build: .
        container_name: ci-api
        volumes:
          - .:/home/node/api
        ports:
          - '${SERVER_PORT}:${SERVER_PORT}'
        depends_on:
          - db-pg
        command: sh -c "/wait && yarn dev"
        environment:
          WAIT_HOSTS: db-pg:5432
        logging:
          driver: 'json-file'
          options:
            max-size: '10m'
            max-file: '5'

    volumes:
      ci-postgres-data:
```

And, this is my `ORM CONFIG`:

```
    {
      "type": "postgres",
      "host": "${DB_HOST}",
      "port": "${DB_PORT}",
      "username": "${DB_USER}",
      "password": "${DB_PASS}",
      "database": "${DB_NAME}",
      "synchronize": true,
      "logging": false,
      "entities": ["dist/src/entity/**/*.js"],
      "migrations": ["dist/src/migration/**/*.js"],
      "subscribers": ["dist/src/subscriber/**/*.js"],
      "cli": {
        "entitiesDir": "dist/src/entity",
        "migrationsDir": "dist/src/migration",
        "subscribersDir": "dist/src/subscriber"
      }
    }
```

I can't imagine the reason for this error, I basically added a script for the node to start after the start of my Postgres where `db-pg` is my Postgres image name.

I can't imagine what went wrong, could someone help me with this?

P.S.: I use `typescript/typeorm`

Answer (score 1):

```
{
  "type": "postgres",
  "host": "db-pg",
  "port": 5432,
  "username": "spirit",
  "password": "api",
  "database": "emasa_ci",
  "synchronize": true,
  "logging": false,
  "entities": ["dist/src/entity/**/*.js"],
  "migrations": ["dist/src/migration/**/*.js"],
  "subscribers": ["dist/src/subscriber/**/*.js"],
  "cli": {
    "entitiesDir": "dist/src/entity",
    "migrationsDir": "dist/src/migration",
    "subscribersDir": "dist/src/subscriber"
  }
}
```

the problem was in my
ormconfig.json (was using .env)